# C# How to Upload image from local to cloud server using amazon s3 bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to transfer file from local machine to cloud server using amazon s3 bucket.
I am stuck with the steps as i am very new to s3 bucket concept. had a code snippet example for listing files in s3 bucket, but no luck on transferring files (using c#). stuck with passing values in `uploadonjectfromfilepathasync()`. not sure what is the objectkey (2nd parameter in the menthod).

```
AmazonS3Config ClientConfig = new AmazonS3Config();
ClientConfig.ServiceURL = S3_HOST_ENDPOINT;
IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY, ClientConfig);

var ObjectList = s3Client.UploadObjectFromFilePathAsync(S3_BUCKET_NAME,<objectkey>,localfilepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Amazon.S3.Transfer` library. Here is an example:

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer


public class Uploader
{
       readonly IAmazonS3 s3Client;
       readonly string bucketName;

       public async Task<string> Upload(string prefix, byte[] data, string ext)
        {
            var uuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            var filename = $"{uuid}.{ext}";
            var key = $"{prefix}/{filename}";
            var stream = new MemoryStream(data);

            using (var transferUtil = new TransferUtility(s3Client))
            {
                await transferUtil.UploadAsync(stream, bucketName, key);
            }

            return filename;
        }
}
```

This is the snippet from the code i use. `prefix` and `ext` are could be optional in your use case. Here these parameters are used to determine the filename (aka `key`) for the file to be saved in s3 bucket. `MemoryStream` is class that serves the given `data` in a stream fashion. `UploadAsync` also accepts variety of sources such as file to path. You should check for the most suitable method for your application.

Comment: hi @sardok , thank you. can you explain me the parameters for upload task? data,prefix and ext?

Comment: i mean where do i pass source and destination details

Comment: Edited the answer @Ameena.